# Can anyone tell me why my token API is returning null?

Tags: c#, json, api, restsharp

I have an API that returns some information. That API requires an access token.

Problem is the JSON is always NULL. My var response and var content is always NULL.

Here is my code - can somebody find the problem and help me please?

```
private void GetWorkList(string Token)
{
        SetWorkListProps();

        var client = new RestClient("http://webserver:8182/api/Labratoary/SearchWorkList");

        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.Method = Method.Post;
        request.AddHeader("Token", Token);
        request.AddJsonBody(new JsonBodyForWorkList
        {
            Id_ReceptionDetail = IdReception,
            ServiceIds = "",
            LabSectionIds = "",
            DeviceIds = DeviceId,
            PatientIds = "",
            FromDateReception = FromDateStr,
            ToDateReception = ToDatestr,
            FromTimeReception = "",
            ToTimeReception = ""
        });

        var response = client.ExecuteAsync(request);
        var content = response.Result.Content;

        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
}
```

Comment: Tokens usually go in an "Authorization" header, not literally "Token" header, but I am not familiar with your API so I cannot say for sure.

Comment: Please provide the code for the API. It sounds like the problem is that the API doesn't return what you expect?

Comment: What's the response status? What's the token look like; is it valid; where did it come from? Are you sure you want a "Token" header?

Comment: Usually, when the response is null there IS NO RESPONSE. I would make sure you have the right URL and are passing the right authorization. I know that's the default response to API related questions but when I run into these problems I'm usually not passing in the authorization in correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I Solve That, That Was Not The API Problem It Is About RestSharp And I Use Another Method To Get My Answer From API ...